# Checking graph is simple or not ,given its degree sequence .

Tags: graph-theory

I don't know what is the way to check this:

Check whether the graph having degree sequence $\{3,3,1,1\}$ is a simple graph or not?

Please help explaining the strategy I must follow to check this...

Comment: Have you tried drawing a simple graph with that degree sequence?

Comment: @Casteels I made four vertices ,and then connected a vertex to other 3 vertices ,but after that I don't understand the way to connect remaining vertices...

Comment: Ok, and now what about the other vertex of degree $3$? Can you draw edges from this vertex so that the remaining two vertices have degree $1$? If there Is no way to do this, then there is no simple graph with that degree sequence!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let the vertices be $v_1,v_2,v_3$, and $v_4$, and suppose that $\deg v_1=\deg v_2=3$. If the graph is simple, and $\deg v_1=3$, $v_1$ must be adjacent to each of the other three vertices. The same is true of $v_2$. Thus, $v_3$ must be adjacent to $v_1$ and to $v_2$; can its degree be $1$? The argument is practically complete at this point, but I’ve included the rest in the spoiler-protected block below; mouse-over to see it.

> Clearly it must have degree at least $2$. (The same is of course true for $v_4$.) Thus, $\langle 3,3,1,1\rangle$ is not the degree sequence of any simple graph.

Comment: as you said the degree of $v_3$ and $v_4$ be atleast $2$ ..Shouldn't it be exactly two..

Comment: @spectraa: All that we can guarantee is that once two of the vertices have degree $3$, the other two have degree at least $2$; they could also have degree $3$ (as they do in the complete graph $K_4$).

Comment: @spectraa: You’re welcome.